# How can I escape reserved URL characters identically from Java and Ruby?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two clients, one written in Java and the other in Ruby, that need to escape reserved URL characters from strings. The problem I have is that I cannot find a library that does the encoding exactly the same on both platforms. The output needs to be exactly the same so the escaped strings can later be compared for equality.

Answer (score 0):

Why compare the URL Strings in their escaped format? Even though the URL's may be escaped differently, you can unescape them and compare the resulting String values. The unescaped values should be identical from both platforms.

Comment: The escaped strings are being stored in a database. Ideally, I would like to select, join, etc. on these fields.

Comment: Store the strings in unescaped form.... that's the only real solution. All other solutions are likely to break at some point.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you're not guaranteed that the URL generated will be consistent. Query parameters can be ordered differently, which will break all attempts to compare the URL as a string.

Instead, you have to break the URLs down into their components. The URI spec is followed well enough that we can do that and retrieve the various parts and compare them.

For example:

```
require 'uri'

URL1 = 'http://www.example.com?foo=1&bar=2'
URL2 = 'http://www.Example.com?bar=2&foo=1'

URL1 == URL2 # => false

url1 = URI.parse(URL1)
url2 = URI.parse(URL2)

(url1.host.downcase == url2.host.downcase) && (URI.decode_www_form(url1.query).sort == URI.decode_www_form(url2.query).sort)
# => true
```

Try comparing `URL1` and `URL2` as strings and it'll fail. Try comparing the query as a string and it'll fail. Do a case-insensitive comparison of the hosts and sort the query components so they're normalized and you have a reasonable chance of comparing things to see if they match.

If you know that the host receiving the query is case-insensitive, you can change shorten it a little:

```
url1 = URI.parse(URL1.downcase)
url2 = URI.parse(URL2.downcase)

(url1.host == url2.host) && (URI.decode_www_form(url1.query).sort == URI.decode_www_form(url2.query).sort)
# => true
```

I've run into hosts that expect case-sensitive parameters in their query, along with position-dependent parameters, so folding everything to lower-case might not work for a particular URL, but for testing equality it should be OK.